# how can I add a listener on the buttons of a fragment in android

Tags: android, layout-inflater

i am trying to display a pop up when i click on an item view.
when the pop up is open the buttons doesn't work.
here is my onItemClick function :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    this.id = position;
    alert.setTitle("Alert");
    alert.setMessage("Souhaitez-vous modifier ou supprimer?");
    alert.setView(R.layout.alert_view);

    LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(this);
    layoutAlert=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_view,null);

    btn_supp = (Button)layoutAlert.findViewById(R.id.btn_supp_alert);
    btn_modif = (Button)layoutAlert.findViewById(R.id.btn_modifier_alert);
    ed_nom = (EditText)layoutAlert.findViewById(R.id.ed_nom_alert);
    ed_prenom = (EditText)layoutAlert.findViewById(R.id.ed_prenom_alert);
    ed_tel = (EditText)layoutAlert.findViewById(R.id.ed_tel_alert);
    System.out.println(Principal.mesContacts.get(position).getNom().toString());
    ed_nom.setText(Principal.mesContacts.get(position).getNom().toString());
    btn_supp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_modif.setOnClickListener(this);
    alert.show();
}
```

and this is my onClick function:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v==btn_supp)
    {
        Principal.mesContacts.remove(id);
        listView.invalidateViews();

    }
    if(v==btn_modif)
    {
        Principal.mesContacts.set(id,new Contact(ed_nom.getText().toString(),ed_prenom.getText().toString(),ed_tel
                .getText().toString()));
       listView.invalidateViews();
    }
}
```

but that doesn't work, I don't know why

Comment: delete the line `alert.setView(R.layout.alert_view);` and add the line `alert.setView(layoutAlert);` before the call to `alert.show();` If this works for you, i'll explain it further in an answer.

Comment: thank you that works! but i didn't understand why!

Comment: i'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay what you basically did is the following:

`alert.setView(R.layout.alert_view);`:

With this line of code, you instruct the `AlertDialog.Builder` class to inflate a new layout from the specified resource `R.layout.alert_view` and set it as the layout of the `AlertDialog`.

With the following lines of code you inflated a **new** layout of the same resource.
For this instance you set the `OnClickListener`. But your constructed layout never got set to the `AlertDialog.Builder` object.

So the `AlertDialog.Builder` wasn't aware of your layout and used the layout specified by `alert.setView(R.layout.alert_view);`. Does that make it clear to you?